# Overriding SessionsControllers is not loggin in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, controller

I want to add OpenID authentication in my web. To do that I have follow several tutorials and used several plugins and gems and finally I manage to do *something* with [devise_openid_authenticatable](https://github.com/nbudin/devise_openid_authenticatable) gem. I also have normal login/password authentication, Facebook authentication and Twitter authentication. Those three work perfectly.

Now I'm trying to override Devise's `Session Controller` , but when I do it, the normal login/password stops working. The error I get is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Sessions#create
     Couldn't find User without an ID
```

The rest of the authentication forms work OK, even the sign up works perfect. It's only the login/password authentication method...

I use Rails 3.0.1, Ruby 1.8.9 and Devise 1.4.9

**routes.rb**

```
MAWeb::Application.routes.draw do

[...]

  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations', :sessions => 'sessions'}
  match '/users/openid' => 'users#openid_sign_in'
  match 'openid/sign_in' => 'openid#sign_in', :as => :openid_sign_in
  get 'openid/create'

  match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
  match '/auth/failure' => 'authentications#failure'

  resources :subscription_contact_datas

  resources :subscription_preferences do
    collection do
      post :create_with_params
    end
    member do
      get 'delete_tag'
    end
    get 'fill_event_id', :on => :member
  end
  resources :event_states

  resources :subscription_profiles do
    collection do
      put :update_profiles
    end
  end

  resources :event_criteria_options

  resources :subscriptions do
    collection do
      get :options_for_event_criteria
    end

  end

  resources :event_criterias
  resources :categories
  resources :user_infos do
      member do
        get 'edit'
      end
  end

  resources :events 

  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'showUserActivity'
    end
  end 

  resources :admins

  resources :subscriptions_from_poi

  root :to => "home#index"

  namespace :user do
    root :to => "users#index"
  end

  namespace :admin do
    root :to => "admins#index"
  end
```

**registrations controller's override works perfectly*

EDIT: Added the most of the routes. The ones I omited are not important in my opinion.

Comment: Please show your complete `config/routes.rb`

Comment: Devise + Omniauth is perfect blend. We have been using them for all major openid providers.

Comment: I used Devise and Omniauth for Twitter and Facebook, but it was imposible for me to adapt to OpenID authentication...